# Empty Console Output Python

Tags: python, selenium, console, output

I added and used undetected_chromedriver library, and after that the program stopped working. Did I do something wrong? **Nothing is written in the console**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
service = Service(executable_path="path")
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, service=service)

driver.get("link")
```

Next comes the code of the program, but it worked well

[Console image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MM2th.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out the options, but the problem was with the path. You need to use `driver_executable_path=""`. And add the module import check `if __name__ == '__main__':`, and put all the code there. Now the program looks like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() #or options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, driver_executable_path="path")

    driver.get("link")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe in the newer version of uc it comes with chromeoptions so you don't need to use selenium.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, version_main=94) #Choose correct version
driver.get('link')
```